# If $E(X_n)=0$ and $E(X_n^2)=1$ then$P(X_n\ge n\,i.o.)=0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, expectation, limsup-and-liminf

I solved exercise 3.6.13 page 40 of Rosenthal's *A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory*(which should appear at the end of chapter 4 about expectations). The fact that I didn't use one of its assumptions ($E(X_n)=0$ for all $n$) makes me doubt about my solution, or about the existence of an interesting different solution. Could you please check it out?

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be defined jointly on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, with $E(X_n)=0$ and $E(X_n^2)=1$ for all $n$. Prove that $P(X_n\ge n\,i.o.)=0$.

i.o. stands for infinitely often. For a sequence $\{A_n\}_n$ of events,

$$\{A_n\,i.o.\}=\limsup_nA_n=\bigcap_{i=1}^{+\infty}\bigcup_{j=i}^{+\infty}A_j.$$

Here's my solution:

The Borel-Cantelli Lemma usually comes handy in such situations. To solve the exercise, it's enough to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}P(X_n\ge n)$ is finite.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We have:

\begin{aligned}
1&=E(X_n^2)\\
&=\int_\Omega X_n^2\,\mathrm{d}P\\
&=\int_{\{X_n^2<n^2\}}X_n^2\,\mathrm{d}P+\int_{\{X_n^2\ge n^2\}}X_n^2\,\mathrm{d}P\\
&\ge\int_{\{X_n^2\ge n^2\}}X_n^2\,\mathrm{d}P\\
&\ge n^2P(X_n^2\ge n^2).
\end{aligned}

Thus $P(X_n^2\ge n^2)\le\dfrac{1}{n^2}$. As $\{X_n\ge n\}\subset\{X_n^2\ge n^2\}$, we get $P(X_n\ge n)\le\dfrac{1}{n^2}$. Hence $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}P(X_n\ge n)$ is finite as desired. ($E(X_n)=0$ for all $n$ was not used)

Comment: Indeed. Maybe they meant to use a variance assumption instead.

Comment: @Scientifica Nice question -- but why do you see fit to accept an answer not addressing it?

Comment: @Did Thank you very much :) (though I felt bad to see that people up voted the answer but not the question. The reason is that what I wanted people to check is "The fact that I didn't use one of its assumptions makes me doubt about my solution, or about the existence of an interesting different solution." Indeed the answerer didn't say that my proof was right, but the fact that no one said so (plus the fact that I didn't spot any error) implicitly means that the proof is right. The answerer also provided another solution that shows the importance of the $E(X_n)=0$ assumption.

Comment: Amusingly, the $E(X_n)=0$ assumption is irrelevant to the result, an assumption such as $E(X_n^2)\leqslant C$ being sufficient.

Comment: @Did Yes you're right. In fact, we could generalize it even furthur: $\sum_n\dfrac{E(X_n^2)}{n^2}$ is finite. Hence even if we had $E(X_n^2)=\sqrt{n}$ (which is not bounded) the result still holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Chebychev's inequality, which is 
$$P(X_{n}\geq n)\leq \frac{Var(X_{n})}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}.$$
Because $Var(X_{n})=E(X_{n}^2)-(E(X_{n}))^2=1$, and the proof of this inequality is easy.

Comment: They did that, but it does not need the centrality since the given bound uses the ordinary second moment.

Comment: I fail to see how this addresses the OP's concerns. One of the upvoters and/or the OP themselves might want to explain?

Comment: @Did It is a different approach to show that $P(X_{n} \geq n)\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_{n} \geq n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$. From the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, we finished the proof.

Comment: Quote: `Could you please check it out?` To check a given proof $\ne$ To provide another proof (since apparently, such trivialities must be stated explicitely...).

Comment: Indeed the answerer didn't say that my proof was right, but the fact that no one said so (plus the fact that I didn't spot any error) implicitly means that the proof is right. The answerer also provided another solution that shows the importance of the $E(X_n)=0$ assumption.